# Set TabItem DataContext Inidividiually?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, datacontext

I have a TabControl with some items in it based on a class. I'd like to bind that class to the TabItem itself so that I can have a mix of user controlled and class controlled TabItems.

I currently have.

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <TextBlock x:Key="TabItem_Prefab" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="A" Name="TabControl_A">
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="TabItem_Prefab"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="B" Name="TabControl_B">
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="TabItem_Prefab"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Options">
        <TextBlock Text="Stuff"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModelTest a = new ViewModelTest() { Name = "string" };
        ViewModelTest b = new ViewModelTest() { Name = "Cheese" };
        TabControl_A.DataContext = a;
        TabControl_B.DataContext = b;
    }
}

public class ViewModelTest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The problem with this is that the tab for TabControl_A shows "cheese" when it should be bound to the one that says "string".

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably lies inside StaticResource TabItem_Prefab. 
It seems to me that the usual Binding works

```
   <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="A" Name="TabControl_A">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="B" Name="TabControl_B">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Options">
                <TextBlock Text="Stuff"/>
            </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Show your StaticResource.

Comment: Resource should be visible now. The problem with writing it all out is that in practice the object I'm duplicating is dozens of lines long so I'd prefer not to simply copy and paste it.